# Why it is necessary for copula functions to be grounded?

Tags: probability, statistics, special-functions

I know what the properties "grounded" and "2-increasing" means in copula functions definition but actually I can't understand the reason behind these two!
I mean why it is necessary for copulas to be grounded and 2-increasing?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

One interpretation of the requirements is from Sklar's theorem which says the joint cumulative of two random variables can be expressed as a Copula whose arguments are the marginal distributions of either random variable. Then the grounded condition makes sure you assign 0 probability when one of the marginals is 0. The 2 increasing is a generalization of the requirement that a one dimensional cdf is increasing. [Here's a nice summary of all this](http://sfb649.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/fedc_homepage/xplore/tutorials/xfghtmlnode13.html).

Comment: Dear Alex, thanks for your beneficial response. About the 2-increasing property, does this property belong to 2-dimension functions? As the dimension increases, for example to 5, is it correct to say this function is 5-increasing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568669/2-increasing-functions

I think in general you want the gradient to point into the positive quadrant of your space. So a $n$ dimensional increasing function would have gradient in the regiion $(+,+,+,\cdots,+)$.