# Analyzing a posible distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have problems analyzing this:
Let $F$ and $G$ be distribution functions, both on $\mathbb{R}$. Now define, for $t\in[0,1]$
$$H_t(x,y) = 
        \begin{cases}
            F(x)^{1-t}G(y) & F(x)\geq G(y) \\
            F(x)G(y)^{1-t} & F(x)\leq G(y)
        \end{cases}
    $$

Is $H_{t}(x,y)$ a distibution function?

I think that the limit (When both tends to infinite is 1 and when just one tends to $-\infty$ is 0) property is true, but... The 2-increasing property and the continuity property I just don't find a counterexample or don't know how to prove that.

Comment: $H_t(x,y)$ looks to me to be a weakly increasing function of $x$ and $y$ because $F(x)$ and $G(y)$ are, and as left-continuous as $F(x)$ and $G(y)$

Comment: @Henry So you think that the 2-increasing property fails? I was trying with that but since we don't know how the functions are, I find kind of difficult to prove that

Comment: @EduardoCuéllar - no, I think the increasing property is present

Comment: @pegasus - is there any reason to believe the derivative has to exist?

Comment: I don't know if the 1-t affects continuity or 2-increasing property, so that's kind of difficult for me to give a proof. Just checked the limits property but I'm stuck now

Comment: @MichaelHardy sorry, you are right. That was a typo

Comment: @Henry It is obvious that $F(x,y)$ is increasing and right continuous, but the hard part is showing that it is [2-increasing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568669/2-increasing-functions).

Comment: @MikeEarnest Right. That's why I posted this because I really don't know how to even start